# VPN is not working after iphone returns from sleep mode

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, nevpnmanager

I have problem with VPN on ios. I use this code.

```
let result = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
result.interfaceTypeMatch = .any
manager.onDemandRules = [result]
manager.isOnDemandEnabled = true
```

Sometimes, if I unlock iphone after 1-2 hours of sleep, VPN is not working. VPN icon in status bar is shown, wifi connection icon is shown, but network is not working (I can't load any page in safari). If I manually reconnect VPN in app or in system settings - it starts to work correctly. I'm using **ipsec** protocol.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved an issue in other way - we replaced **ipsec** with **ikev2** and now VPN is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with IPSec protocols, but have some experience with VPNs in Network Extensions. Override the sleep and wake methods in your `PacketTunnelProvider`. You should specify there how the tunnel should behave when it goes to sleep and in the wake method how to reactivate it. See [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/291454#291454) answer in Apple's forums.

You should also set [`disconnectOnSleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnprotocol/1405983-disconnectonsleep#) to `false` to prevent the tunnel from disconnecting when it goes to sleep (self explanatory).